# Converting single thread c# code to multi thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have the following code that i want to convert to multi threading using c# 4.0. Is it possible to do that? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

I have a button start start the process and it calls the following function

```
private void ProcessData()
{
    //clear some ui text fields and disable start button and enable cancel button and set status to working
    //open database connection
    try
    {
        //populate ui multi line textbox saying that it is getting data from database
        var dsResult = new DataSet();
        //populate dataset
        //populate ui multi line textbox saying that it finished getting data from database
        //close connection

        if (dsResult.Tables.Count == 1 && dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //populate another field saying how much records we got
            int iCount = 1;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (_stop)
                {
                    //set the status as forced stop
                    return;
                }
                //populate the currently processed record count using iCount
                //populate ui multi line textbox indicating which item that it is starting to work using dr["Item"]
                //call some external function to process some data, inside this function i have to update ui multi line textbox as well
                var dataFile = SearchDataFile(dr["Item"].ToString());
                if (dataFile == null)
                {
                    //populate ui multi line textbox indicating that item was not found
                    iCount++;
                    continue;
                }
                //call another external function to process some data, inside this function i have to update ui multi line textbox as well
                UpdateDataFile(dataFile, folderId, dr, dr["Item"].ToString());
                iCount++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //populate ui multi line textbox indicating no data found
        }
        //update status saying that it is complete
        tsslblStatus.Text = "STATUS : COMPLETE";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //close connection
        //populate ui multi line textbox indicating error occured
        //update status to error
    }
    finally
    {
        //re adjust ui and enabling start and disable stop
        //set _stop variable to false
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you experiencing any slowness if your application? Which parts do you want us to move?

Comment: be careful of multi threading and GUI applications. Multi threading might make your GUI unresponsive.

Comment: @BossRoss, why is that?

Comment: @BossRoss, I think not using multi-threading is what causes your UI to be unresponsive.

Comment: I refer you to this article for a complete and full explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: I voted to close as "too broad" because there are several issues that must be addressed to answer this question. I would consider separating your UI from your business logic. I would also investigate the thread-safety issues around using a DataSet from different threads. The naming of your methods seems to imply that you're using file IO. Are you sure that throwing extra threads at what could well be an IO bottleneck is a good idea? See what I mean? Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

First split your logic

```
SomeJobA();
SomeJobB();
SomeJobC();
...
```

then do some *multi-threading*

```
start SomeJobA() thread/task
start SomeJobB() thread/task
start SomeJobC() thread/task
...
to wait or not to wait for them to finish?
```

To update UI from other thread use `Invoke` / `BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to use the `Parallel.ForEach` method, so instead of

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
```

use

```
 Parellel.Foreach(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows, dr =>
 {
   //foreach body code goes here.
 });
```

**However**, if you are trying to update an algorithm that manipulates the UI  to take advantage of concurrency you are going to have a bad time.  Win form applications (and if I recall correctly, Win 8 / phone apps) do *not* allow you to manipulate the UI (ie write to a textbox) from any thread other than the main thread.

In order for you to parallelize this algorithm properly, you'll need to separate out all of the code that manipulates the UI.

You can use the `TaskFactory` to marshal out the work you want to do in parallel:

```
public class MyState{
   public string Example {get;set;}
}

private MyState _state;

private void MethodCalledFromUIThread()
{
    //Update UI.
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;

    //Start parallel work in a new thread.
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => ThreadedMethod())
        //Wait for background threads to complete
        .Wait();

     //Update UI with result of processing.
     TextBox1.Text = _state.Example;
}

private void ThreadedMethod()
{
     //load dsResult

     Parallel.ForEach(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows, dr =>
     {
         //process data in parallel.
     }

     //Update the State object so the UI thread can get access to the data

     _state = new MyState{Example = "Data Updated!";}
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this approach as well